# Select value from Object in ComboBox

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a Java Object which I want to edit using this code. The value which I want to get from this obj.getSizeBetweenMessages() is 10:

```
ObservableList<Integer> zoptionsm = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            obj.getSizeBetweenMessages(), 90);
        ComboBox<Integer> zcombom = new ComboBox<>(zoptionsm);
        zcombom.getSelectionModel().select(obj.getSizeBetweenMessages());
        zcombom.setEditable(true);
        gpm.add(zcombom, 1, 1);
```

For some reason the ComboBox is empty and the value into the Object is not displayed. Could you give me some idea where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `getSizeBetweenMessages()` method is returning an int, (not an Integer), you're relying on autoboxing both when you pass the result to `FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)` and `zcombom.getSelectionModel().select(...)`. In the first case, this works, because there is no appropriate `observableArrayList(...)` method taking an int, but in the second case there is a `select(...)` method accepting an int, and that is the one that gets invoked. So if `getSizeBetweenMessages()` returns 10, you are trying to select the item at position 10 (not the item 10 itself), and since that's out of bounds nothing gets selected.

The fix is to create an `Integer` object by hand:

```
Integer sizeBetweenMessages = new Integer(obj.getSizeBetweenMessages());
ObservableList<Integer> zoptionsm = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            sizeBetweenMessages, 90);
        ComboBox<Integer> zcombom = new ComboBox<>(zoptionsm);
        zcombom.getSelectionModel().select(sizeBetweenMessages);
        zcombom.setEditable(true);
        gpm.add(zcombom, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Autoboxing is sometimes convenient, but it doesn't play nice with method overloading.
`List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)); numbers.remove(3);` is the canonical example.